# column id does not belong to table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to import a CSV file into SQL server database

This is my code, can't find the problem :(

```
foreach(DataRow importRow in KeminRecipe.Rows) {

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO KeminRecipe (ID,DateAndTime,Recipe,ReadingSensor,LabResult,MoistureSensor,DryPoint,WetPoint,Enabled,Error,BatchTime,BatchSize,MoistAdd,ProductAIncluded,ProductBIncluded,LastUser,LastAccess) " + "VALUES (@ID,@DateAndTime,@Recipe,@ReadingSensor,@LabResult,@MoistureSensor,@DryPoint,@WetPoint,@Enabled,@Error,@BatchTime,@BatchSize,@MoistAdd,@ProductAIncluded,@ProductBIncluded,@LastUser,@LastAccess)", conn);

//here the error displays starting with ID//  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", importRow["ID"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAndTime", importRow["DateAndTime"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Recipe", importRow["Recipe"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReadingSensor", importRow["ReadingSensor"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LabResult", importRow["LabResult"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MoistureSensor", importRow["MoistureSensor"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DryPoint", importRow["DryPoint"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WetPoint", importRow["WetPoint"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enabled", importRow["Enabled"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Error", importRow["Error"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchTime", importRow["BatchTime"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchSize", importRow["BatchSize"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MoistAdd", importRow["MoistAdd"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductAIncluded", importRow["ProductAIncluded"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductBIncluded", importRow["ProductBIncluded"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastUser", importRow["LastUser"]);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastAccess", importRow["LastAccess"]);

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}

private void BROWSE(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog CSV = new OpenFileDialog();
        CSV.DefaultExt = ".csv";
        CSV.Filter = "Comma Separated (*.csv)|*.csv";
        CSV.ShowDialog();

        CsvFolderPath.Text = CSV.FileName;
    }

private void IMPORT(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CsvFolderPath.Text )) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose a csv file");
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            DataTable KeminRecipe = GetDataFromFile();

            if (KeminRecipe != null) ;
            SaveImportDataToDatabase(KeminRecipe);

            MessageBox.Show("Import Complete");
        }



    }
```

CSV Data:

*Column* "ID";"Date and Time";"Recipe";"Reading Sensor";"Lab Result %";"Moisture Sensor %";"Dry Point";"Wet Point";"Enabled";"Error";"Batch Time [s]";"Batch Size [kg]";"Moist. Add. [%]";"Product 1 Included";"Product 2 Included";"LastUser";"LastAccess"

*VALUE* 19;04/21/2016 09:45:49;101;4448;8.8;0.0;1;0;0;-1.19;309;2000;0.0;1;0;operator;11/02/2018 00:00:01

Gives me an error:

> column id does not belong to table

Comment: How your excel file looks like?

Comment: Use the debugger and check which line throws this

Comment: Does your table [KeminRecipe] has ID column? Oo

Comment: do you have id coulmn in table? is it identity and auto increment?

Comment: When i open it with notepad++ it looks as i showed and when opened with excel it shows a few more columns but they are not of importance for me. Also all columns exist in sql server and i can run querys on them. The ID column did not have a primary key but i added it later and no help there too

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I suggest you to use the debugger to see how your input table is made. Also if you put the first lines of your CSV we could have a better view on your problem (also the code that loads the CSV would be helpful)

Comment: Csv values added and i wish i was a good debugger but i will try.

Comment: Please add the KeminRecipe  table (cols + cols meta data)

Comment: I have added all relevant code now. Hope u guys have an idea!

Comment: Hey Guys i checked the Datatable Keminrecipe after IMPORT and it only has one column VS says... How can i be sure that the contentof the CSV is split in different columns?? should there be a "," or a ; between every column??

Comment: Last Update when i check the content of the Datarow "ImportRow" it contains all the data of the csv(810 rows and they all contain the complete data). It sucks im like an inch away from the silly solution.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have found the solution to my problem. Answer consists out of two solutions.

1) A file with csv extension in my case was separated with ; in stead of the ,. In my code i streamed the csv file (streamreader)using the , separation .Thats why it didnt work.
VS red the data as one column in stead of many columns.

```
 string[] headerColumns = header.Split(';'); // so i changed , to ;
                foreach (string headerColumn in headerColumns)
                {
                    CSVData.Columns.Add(headerColumn);
                }

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;

                    string[] fields = line.Split(';'); // so i changed , to ;
                    DataRow importedRow = CSVData.NewRow();
```

2) The CSV file contained columns as "Columntitle". I had to remove the "" so my code could recognize the header i used in my sql database .

I have found both solutions using the VS property to check what data was contained in my strings or Datatables.